# Windows 8 RP installation : Booting from USB fails

Tags: windows-8-preview

I want to install Windows 8 RP using my pen drive.

I have made it bootable using Windows 7 USB DVD tool. I have changed the boot order and set my pen drive's priority first. When I start my computer, I can see the bootscreen of Windows 8 RP (black screen and big "Windows" written on it), but the setup doesn't actually start.

Then my Windows XP starts running automatically. Also I don't want to run the setup from Windows Explorer itself because it will install in the same drive where XP remains.

Comment: can you specify what hardware are you installing the win8 rp.. and the OS bit version(x86/ x64)

Comment: try making the pendrive again. either pen drive is faulty or your system doesnt support win 8

Comment: Problem solved people ! I formatted my C drive using windows xp installation CD and then tried to boot from the pen drive, magically I was then able to boot from the pen drive and installed windows 8 rp successfully, thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: @slhck - Does the tag `Windows 8` really apply here? This question was asked released well before the `RTM` build was even released.  Who knows if the problem was because it was a preview build or was just a configuration problem.  If it was the later then applying the `Windows 8` tag is appliciable.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know, I didn't add it. But you're right, the `-preview` makes more sense here.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the CPU x64 are not supported by the win8 rp x64 version. You can read through the [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itproinstall/thread/f3846fb7-0db9-446d-bc8c-33d34ff47122) to get an idea about what is the actual reason of it not getting installed.

Edit: not motherboard but CPU. Corrected my answer

Comment: How can a motherboard not support Windows 8 if it supported Windows 7? If anything it sounds like a CPU problem.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a BIOS upgrade avaliable, try that.

I had to upgrade the BIOS on my laptop before I was able to get it to boot the Windows installer from USB, so that might help you too.